reading tif file shows framecount 1, but Microsoft photos shows multiple pages
I have more than a hundred tif files to import images from.  When I am reading a tif file, it shows a framecount of 1.  This indicates to me one page.  However, when I view the file in Microsoft Photos, it shows multiple pages that you can scroll through.
I need to programatically scroll through the pages using c#.  Then, when a page is selected, I would save it as a jpeg.
Can someone help me understand how to work through the tif pages.
The code below works in .net and displays the first page.
Thanks in advance
System.Drawing.Image img;
System.Drawing.Image[] images;
int frameCount;
if (Filedatagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString() == "tif")
{
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(in_directory_path);
    frameCount = img.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
    images = new System.Drawing.Image[frameCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
    {
        img.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, i);
        images[i] = (System.Drawing.Image)img.Clone();
    }
    img.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, 0);
    pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)img.Clone();
}


You can extract some code from this post
